# Render component template outside it with vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a template:

```
var playersList = Vue.extend({
    props: ['players'],
    template: '#players-template'
});

Vue.component('players', playersList);

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    methods: {
        someMethod: function() {
            //JSON data from request comes here
            //Want to render template of players component with that data
        }
    }
});
```

I'm new with Vue.js and don't know how could I make it possible. How can I render the template with data from AJAX request? Someone posted a solution with `v-view` but documentation for it is gone at official website.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the data in your Vue instance where the response is going to be stored

```
var playersList = Vue.extend({
    template: '#players-template',
    props: ['players']
    }
});

Vue.component('players', playersList);

new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: {
      players: ''
    },
    methods: {
        someMethod: function() {
            //JSON data from request comes here
            //Want to render template of players component with that data
            this.$set('players', data);
        }
    }
});

in your html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="player in players">
      <players :players="players"></players>
    </li>
  </ul>
<template id="players-template">
    <p>{{player.name}}</p>
</template>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the Vue app on the `body` element, you can use its component anywhere within that element.  Since you named the component players, you'd render it like this:

```
<body>
    <players :players="players"></players>
</body>
```

Then in your Vue

```
new Vue({
el: 'body',
data: function(){
    return { players:[] }
},
methods: {
    someMethod: function() {
        //var result = ajax result
        this.players = result;
    }
}
});
```

Since `players` is a prop on your list component, you pass it in with `:players="players"`.  Then if `players` updates on the parent app, the list component would automatically update according to the new list.